# How to count number of instance of a word starting at another word

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, search

I need to `grep` the MySQL-error log starting at today's date formatted like:

```
`date +"%y%m%d"` (140710)
```

And look for all instances of the word `partitioned`.

I've tried various things to no avail. This seemed to work:

```
more +/"`date +"%y%m%d"`" mysql-error.log | grep -c partitioned
```

However, if the log file doesn't contain any entries from today, then instead of returning zero, it searches the entire file and returns a number for the entire file.

I need it to return zero, if there are no entries from today, not `grep` the entire file and count the results.

Is there some better way of doing this, using `sed` or `awk` or something?

---

Technically, what I suppose I need to count is `} partitioned {` followed by a string of alpha numberic characters, }) because portioned { (without any string) } could occur and shouldn't be counted.

That's not a strict requirement though. I'd be happy just counting instances of the word `partitioned`.

Here is an example of the log file:

```
140109 12:25:07 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,c4819ddf-7952-11e3-89fc-4f9f1bfa267f,3) memb {
    c4819ddf-7952-11e3-89fc-4f9f1bfa267f,
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
    f85c2e70-7952-11e3-a759-aa8332246e85,
})
140109 12:25:07 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 85)
```

Comment: I think you'd need something like  `grep -ce "$(date +%y%m%d)" -e "partitioned" /var/log/mysqld.log`  or whatever path your mysql log is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GNU sed` anhd `grep`, you can try:

```
sed -n "/$(date +%y%m%d)/,\$p" file | grep -c partitioned
```

`/pattern/,$` matched first pattern to the end of file.

With your input:

```
$ sed -n "/$(date +%y%m%d)/,\$p" 1.txt | grep -c partitioned
1
```

Without matching date:

```
$ sed -n "/$(date +%y%m%d)/,\$p" 1.txt | grep -c partitioned
0
```

Comment: Perfect - that seems to work! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try chaining two greps together:

```
grep `date +"%y%m%d"` mysql-error.log | grep -c partitioned
```

Or even simpler:

```
grep -c "`date +%y%m%d`.*partitioned" mysql-error.log
```

**EDIT**

As the date and the word 'partitioned' are on different lines, then:

```
d=$(date +"%y%m%d"); awk '/'$d'/,EOF {print $0}' mysql-error.log | grep -c partitioned
```

Or:

```
awk '/'$(date +%y%m%d)'/,EOF {print $0}' mysql-error.log | grep -c partitioned
```

Comment: So the word partitioned doesn't appear on the same line as the date. So grepping for only the date and then trying to search that doesn't work.

Comment: Confirmed the awk also works.